# Iterating through divs from code behind c#

Tags: c#, innerhtml

Anyone has an idea of how I can make this less redundant? I need to populate the inner html of multiple div elements on the client with the same content.

Client:

```
<div id="projectList_dialog1" class="listView" runat="server"></div>
<div id="projectList_dialog2" class="listView" runat="server"></div>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void loadProjectList()
    {
        var projectsPath = userDataPath + @"\" + username + @"\Projects";

        if (Directory.Exists(projectsPath))
        {
            var projects = Directory.GetDirectories(userDataPath + @"\" + username + @"\Projects");

            projectList_dialog1.InnerHtml = "<table>";
            projectList_dialog2.InnerHtml = "<table>";

            projectList_dialog1.InnerHtml += "<tr><td>Name</td><td>Date modified</td></tr>";
            projectList_dialog2.InnerHtml += "<tr><td>Name</td><td>Date modified</td></tr>";

            List<string> storedProjectNamesList = new List<string>();
            for (var i = 0; i < projects.Length; i++)
            {
                var storedProjectName = projects[i].Remove(0, projects[i].LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
                storedProjectNamesList.Add('"' + storedProjectName + '"');

                var lastModified = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(storedProjectName);
                projectList_dialog1.InnerHtml += "<tr class='" + storedProjectName + "' onclick='listViewAction(event)'><td>" + storedProjectName + "</td><td>" + lastModified + "</td></tr>";
                projectList_dialog2.InnerHtml += "<tr class='" + storedProjectName + "' onclick='listViewAction(event)'><td>" + storedProjectName + "</td><td>" + lastModified + "</td></tr>";
            }
            projectList_dialog1.InnerHtml += "</table>";
            projectList_dialog2.InnerHtml += "</table>";

            storedProjectNames = string.Join(",", storedProjectNamesList);
        }
        else
        {
            serverMessage.InnerHtml = "Code (0x3): The system cannot find the path specified.";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign the data to a local variable like `innerHtml`, only change `InnerHtml` of the elements once

```
protected void loadProjectList()
{
    var projectsPath = userDataPath + @"\" + username + @"\Projects";

    if (Directory.Exists(projectsPath))
    {
        var projects = Directory.GetDirectories(userDataPath + @"\" + username + @"\Projects");

        //create a variable
        var innerHtml = "<table><tr><td>Name</td><td>Date modified</td></tr>";

        List<string> storedProjectNamesList = new List<string>();
        for (var i = 0; i < projects.Length; i++)
        {
            var storedProjectName = projects[i].Remove(0, projects[i].LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
            storedProjectNamesList.Add('"' + storedProjectName + '"');

            var lastModified = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(storedProjectName);

            //add to that variable
            innerHtml += "<tr class='" + storedProjectName + "' onclick='listViewAction(event)'><td>" + storedProjectName + "</td><td>" + lastModified + "</td></tr>";
        }
        innerHtml += "</table>";

        //NOW set innerhtml on the objects
        projectList_dialog1.InnerHtml = innerHtml;
        projectList_dialog2.InnerHtml = innerHtml;

        storedProjectNames = string.Join(",", storedProjectNamesList);
    }
    else
    {
        serverMessage.InnerHtml = "Code (0x3): The system cannot find the path specified.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks DLeh! Your solution is so simple and clean. I feel as if I might have done this in the past for another project; can't believe I didn't see that. I guess you can sometimes go blind looking at the same code for hours. :P